# Azure Devops pipeline triggers when it should not from Bitbucket

Tags: azure, triggers, bitbucket, devops, pipeline

I want my Azure Devops pipeline, configured with an azure-pipelines.yml file in Bitbucket, to only trigger when a certain directory (named `terraform-aci`) is edited and merged. However, when I updated and merged a different directory, the pipeline still ran which I did not expect, nor want.

My directory structure is like:

```
repo / terraform / terraform-aci
                 / azurerm-mg
```

My azure-pipelines.yml build trigger is:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - terraform/terraform-aci/*
```

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers), "when you specify paths, you must explicitly specify branches to trigger on." I don't understand why my pipeline triggered when I merged a change to the `azurerm-mg` directory only (and did not touch my `terraform-aci` directory which was set as the trigger).

Comment: Was this a one time event? What if you were to exclude the root so it should exclude everything except that folder?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually have many other folders defined under my `terraform` directory, so I am hoping there's a better tactical solution then having to exclude all of the other folder paths under this directory. I just tried updating my trigger path to include: `- terraform/terraform-aci`, dropping the `/*` from the end to see if that made any difference (even though wildcards should be allowed), but it did not. Updating any folder content other than `terraform/terraform-aci` still triggered the pipeline.

Comment: RESOLVED: Turns out I needed to add `pr: none` to my azure-pipelines.yml, per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers): "If no pr triggers appear in your YAML file, pull request validations are automatically enabled for all branches, as if you wrote the following pr trigger. This configuration triggers a build when any pull request is created, and when commits come into the source branch of any active pull request."